# SharePoint 2016 and update windows server from 2012 R2 to 2022

Tags: sharepoint, windows-server-2012-r2, sharepoint-2016, windows-server-2022

I have two servers running Windows Server 2012 R2. I have a SharePoint farm installed on these servers, with one dedicated to SQL and the other to applications. I need to upgrade only the operating system to Windows Server 2022. Would this affect the SharePoint environment? What is the best practice to accomplish this? God willing.

I don't have another servers now to make new enviroment, so nothing to do yet.

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, SharePoint Server 2016 supports Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard or Datacenter, Windows Server 2016 Standard or Datacenter and Windows Server 2019 Standard or Datacenter.